# What is the probability the class lasts over $60$ minutes?

Tags: probability, statistics

### The Question

> Classes are supposed to last a maximum of $60$ minutes, but usually
> run over time. Let $X$ be the duration of the class, in minutes. The PDF
> of $X$ is
>
> $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac{1}{300} & 0  \le x \lt 60 \\
>  \frac{1}{60} & 60 \le x \lt 90\\ \frac{1}{100} & 90 \le x \lt 120 \\ 0
>  & \text{otherwise.} \end{array}\right.$$
>
> 1. What is the probability the class lasts over $60$ minutes?\
> 2. What is the $0.9$ quantile of $X$?

### My Understanding

1. My thought process was this, $1/60 +1/100 = 2.6\%$ it seems extremely low, but $1/300$ is a very low probability, making me think that $60-120$ minutes is much more possible.
2. Would this just be $115$ minutes? because its $90\%$ of $120$?

Comment: The pdf is the density function.  You have to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

$P(0 < X \le 60) = 60/300 = 0.2,\;$
$P(60 < X \le 90) = 30/60 = 0.5,\;$ and $\;$
$P(90 < X \le 120) = 30/100= 0.3.$

Maybe sketch the density function, essentially
consisting of three rectangles.

You will see that $P(X > 60) = 0.5 + 0.3 = 0.8$
and $P(X \le 60) = 0.2,$ so the 20th percentile is 60.

Also, the 70th percentile is 90.

With that start, can you find the 90th percentile,
which is $c$ such that $P(X \le c) = 0.9?$

Comment: So if .5 + .3 = .8 which is the 70th percentile and you state is 90, I am a little confused how these numbers correlate exactly? would the 90th percentile just be 110 based off that logic?

Comment: Because $P(X \le 60) = .2$ we know 60 is the 20th percentile. Because $P(X\le 90) = .7$ we know 90 is 70th percentile. Now, if $P(X \le 110) = .9,$ then 110 is the 90th percentile. // Changed the line breaks in my answer so you won't be confused about 70th percentile.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to realise that the probability of the class lasting says exactly 61min, is zero, but there is a measurable probability of class taking anywhere between say 60 and 61 minutes. This probability is the area under the probability density function between 60 and 61.
To understand and solve these problem follow the steps

1. Draw the PDF.
2. Mark the points between which you whould like to calculate probability.
3. Find the area.